# How to get custom User object from AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent / AuthenticationSuccessEvent object

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-webflow

I'm trying to show no of invalid attempts of user using spring security.I'm using a custom User class to get additional user details other than username and password. I've created two listener classes i.e. AuthenticationSuccessEventListener & AuthenticationFailureListener to update user's invalid attempts.

Now in the onApplicationEvent method i'm trying to get custom User object (CustomUserDetails) like shown below:

```
    @Component
    public class AuthenticationFailureListener implements ApplicationListener<AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent> {
        @Autowired
        private ILoginDAO loginDAO ;            
        @Override
        public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent event) {
            CustomUserDetails user = (CustomUserDetails)event.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();//I get ClassCastException here.
            String strUserID = user.getUserID();
            CustomUserDetails customUser = loginDAO.loadUserByUsername(strUserID);
            if (customUser != null){
        ...
       } } }
```

event.getAuthentication().getPrincipal() returns a String i.e. username which i'm trying to cast it to CustomUserDetails (custom User class) and i get error.

P.S - I'm entering userid/password in login page and hence i pass userid as parameter for all the methods including loadUserByUsername(strUserID).

How can i get my custom User object in the listener class from AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent / AuthenticationSuccessEvent object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event just contains the authentication request object, i.e. the `Authentication` which was passed to the `AuthenticationManager` and which failed. So it will contain the submitted username as the principal.

Authentication may have failed for a variety of reasons, including a non-existent username, and in fact doesn't even need to involve a `UserDetails` object at all, so if you want the full information you will need to load it using the username.

Alternatively you could customize an `AuthenticationProvider` to perform the additional work you want in the implementation itself, rather than via an event.

Comment: Luke thanks for your response. Regarding first approach i have a question. In my login table in D/B 'userID' is primary key and 'username' is not unique and can be same for different users.Hence in login page user enters 'userID' instead of 'username'. In this case how can i pick the matching records from D/B using 'username'?

Comment: The value should be whatever the user entered in the login form - i.e. what Spring Security calls the "username". If you call it "userId" it doesn't really matter.